# Preventing users login from non authorized area

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-security

To avoid me 403 errors when a user tries to access a forbidden area and avoid user sign in into that area I need to prevent users from logging if do not have the proper credentials.

Let me explain a little better, suppose I'm the `X` user `ROLE_USER`, user `X` can access the frontend but should not be able to log into the backend, just as we have the user `Y` and `ROLE_ADMIN`, user `Y` could log into the backend but not in the frontend, do understand me? How I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets assume that I'm user Adam with role 'ROLE_ADMIN'. I can't login to frontend.

You should simple add this code to your controllers:

```
  if( $this->get('security.context')->isGranted('YOUR ROLE') )
            return new Response('yea!');
```

So, If you want to secure BackendController and let to login users with 'ROLE_ADMIN' you should add this code:

```
if( $this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN') )
                return new Response('You are granted to see this site.');
```

This code checks if current user (me) has role ROLE_ADMIN. If you want to check if user has 'ROLE_ADMIN' **AND** doesn't have 'ROLE_USER' just add:

```
$security = $this->get('security.context');
if( $security->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN') && !$security->isGranted('ROLE_USER') )
                    return new Response('You are not granted to see this site.');
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your routes are [correctly secured](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#denying-access-roles-and-other-authorization), you have to hide / show links to restricted areas in your twig templates.

From the [Symfony2 doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#retrieving-the-user-in-a-template) :

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
    <a href="...">LogIntoBackend</a>
{% endif %}
```

Related :

- [Symfony2 security functions in Twig? How to check the user's role?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8810284/symfony2-security-functions-in-twig-how-to-check-the-users-role)
- [Symfony2: How to hide link in Twig based on permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085130/symfony2-how-to-hide-link-in-twig-based-on-permissions)